# CSS sliding effect won't work in Chrome?

Tags: css, animation, slider

I have this code which works fine in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome. What it does is, it starts a slide image animation, over existing image when the cursor is on it. Is there any part of the code that Chrome does not support?

```
<td width="214">
    <div style="margin-left:19px; margin-top:-8px">
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="icon1.png">
<a href="http://www.somesite.com" target="_blank">
    <img id="slide" src="slide_img.png" />
    </a>
</div>  
</div>
</td>


.wrapper{
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 197px;
height: 162px;
} 

#slide{
position: absolute;
left: -197px;
width: 197px;
height: 162px;
background: transparent;
transition: 0.5s;
}

.wrapper:hover #slide {
transition: 0.3s;
left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Alex you can accept an answer or try clearing your doubts if any :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in the first image in the wrapper. Try providing a bacground to the div rather than using the img tag

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8Y3J/)

Modified html

```
<td width="214">
<div style="margin-left:19px; margin-top:-8px">
<div class="wrapper" >

<a href="http://www.biography.com/imported/images/Biography/Images/Profiles/K/Kaka-559558-1-402.jpg" target="_blank">
    <img id="slide" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-9qLJXsHoVag/T_rA4WlE-PI/AAAAAAAAB0I/I4gHxidRYEY/s320/kaka.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>  
</div>
</td>
```

and css

```
.wrapper{
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 197px;
height: 162px;
    background:url('http://www.biography.com/imported/images/Biography/Images/Profiles/K/Kaka-559558-1-402.jpg')
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But there's a slight problem though. With background in CSS I'd have to make seperate class for every icon. I have many. Is there a way to replace that with HTML?

Comment: use any of the two fiddle you want or will suit you :) for the second one no need to add extra classes :) change the image's display

Answer (score 0):

You need to give Prefix for this

```
.cssname 
{
transition: 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
}
```